# Find the Area of a Strange Shape

Tags: python

I need to find the area of the shaded region using code but I have no idea how to write a program that can do this. Can someone help me?

[image: Farmer John's Field]

Comment: Assuming A,B,C,D are centered in the circles, wouldn't it just be the area of the square minus the area of one circle?

Comment: What all details are you given? The Image? The co-ordinates?

Comment: Are you trying to have your program interpret this image? Or some mathematical description of the figures?

Comment: Please explain how this is a problem in computer programming. It looks like a fairly simple geometry problem to me. Do you need to write a function that accepts the radius of one of the circles and returns the area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four circles of radius `r`, situated in a square shape and tangent to each other. Then, you have a square connecting the centers of the four circles.

Since each side of the square is two radii (`2r`), the total area of the square is `4r**2`.

We can find the area between the circles by subtracting the area of the parts of circles that are within the square. A quarter of each circle is inside the square. Since the area of a full circle is `pi * r**2`, the area of one quarter of a circle is `1/4 pi r**2`. There are four of these inside the square, so we add them all up to find that the total area of "parts of the circle" inside the square is `pi r**2`.

Finally, we subtract that from the area of the square. Whatever's left must be the area of the space between the circles inside the square:

```
= (4 - pi) * r**2
```

---

This is a mathematical question, not a programming one. Hopefully you can adapt this solution to whichever problem you're trying to solve; but if you want us to be more helpful or provide a solution more targeted to your particular problem, you're gonna have to provide some code or a more generalized description of what you want your code to do, in terms of inputs and outputs.